# Как в Django REST, AngularJs выполнить удаление не по id?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

В urls.py

```
url(r'^someurl/(?P<pk>\d+)/', MyApi.as_view(), name='delete')
```

где `name='delete'` - это имя функции

Т.е. `URL` будет вида

```
...someurl/123/
```

В views.py

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
item = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk) 
item.delete() 
print(pk) 
return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

В контроллере вызываю

```
$http.delete('someurl/' + id + '/');
```

При таком запросе удалится объект с номером = `id`

Но сейчас мне нужно удалить объект, не зная его `id`. Я знаю только значение поля `image_url`.

Вызывать

```
$http.delete('someurl/1/');
```

где 1 - это любое число, ни с чем не связанное, т.к. `delete` требует такого формата вызова;
и передавать image_url в качестве дополнительного параметра в request? Таким образом:

```
$http.delete('someurl/1/', {'image_url': 'какой-то урл'});
```

Есть ли более элегантное решение, чем приписывать магическое число в конце?

**Обновление:**

При использовании

```
$http.delete('someurl/1/', {'image_url': 'какой-то урл'});
```

и в view.py

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    image_url = request.data['image_url']
    item = self.model.objects.get(image_url=image_url)
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Возникает ошибка 403.

**Обновление 2**

```
class SortedItemsAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
model = SortedItem

permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated
]

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'POST']:
        return SortedItemIdSerializerBasic
    return SortedItemSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('order')

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {'user': request.user.id}
    data.update(request.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)

    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    for order, element in enumerate(request.data['sorted']):
        self.model.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, id=element).update(
            order=order
        )
    print(request.data['sorted'])
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    item = self.model.objects.get(item_id=pk)
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Если меняю на

```
 def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        item = self.model.objects.get(item_id=request.GET['id'])
        item.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

и, конечно, передаю в `request.data` параметр `id`, который в точности равен pk - возникает ошибка `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`.

Comment: Можно сделать отдельный url, в котором удалять по id картинки или другому уникальному атрибуту

Comment: @FeroxTL как добавить урл для вызова собственной функции?

Comment: что значит собственной функции? Если вы хотите получить url для instance'а конкретной модели, то вы можете переопределить её метод get_absolute_url и вызывать его

Comment: @FeroxTL не совсем. Вы писали выше про "сделать отдельный url", уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы имели в виду? Если я правильно понял, для этого отдельного url нужен еще свой метод в представлении для API? Или переопределять delete()?

Comment: Подскажите что у вас за поле image_url и почему вы делаете ```item = self.model.objects.get(image_url=image)``` если image у вас не определён

Comment: @FeroxTL прошу прощения, неправильно написал в посте, должно быть `self.model.objects.get(image_url=image_url)`. image_url - это поле url у image = models.ImageField, где image - это поле в искомой модели. img_url - это поле, по которому должен осуществляться поиск/удаление

Comment: Во-первых посмотрите какой текст в 403 ошибке (в инспекторе сети в вашем брвузере). Полагаю, что вы просто забыли csrf

Comment: @FeroxTL сейчас 500 ошибка. Если я делаю так:
`def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    item = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)`
  Все работает. Вот так выдает 500 ошибку:  
`def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    item = self.model.objects.get(id=request.data['id'])
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)` В обоих случаях выполняю DELETE /someurl/номер/ в request.data - 'id': тот же номер

Comment: Так какую ошибку то выдаёт? Скорее всего id нет в data. Да и к тому же так неправильно, правильнее - request.GET['id']

Comment: @FeroxTL спасибо, исправил на `GET['id']`. Обновил вопрос, добавил код. Выдает ошибку `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

Comment: @FeroxTL как можно проверить, что передается в функцию delete? куда можно вывести print(...)?

Comment: Да, можно сделать print(request.GET), выведется в консоль с runserver

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29614/discussion-between-emm-and-feroxtl).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете *rest_framework*, то можно использовать декоратор [@list_route](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

```
 @list_route(method=['delete'])
 def remove_image(self, request):
    image_url = request.data['image_url']
    item = self.model.objects.get(image_url=image_url)
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```